# LetLtxMacro not working as expected

Tags: macros

If the lines commented out are substituted for those above them, the index is not set. Why not?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\def\fn#1#2{%
\hyperpage{#2} n.\,#1%
}%

\LetLtxMacro{\oldindex}{\index}
\newcommand{\is}[1]{%
\if@noftnote%
\index{#1}%
%\oldindex{#1}%
\else%
\index{#1|fn{\number\value{footnote}}}%
%\oldindex{#1|fn{\number\value{footnote}}}%
\fi%
}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
Cheese.\footnote{\is{cake}cake.}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\LetLtxMacro` *does* work as expected. `\oldindex` has the meaning of `\index` *at the time of the assignment*, especially this is placed *before* `\makeindex`,
where LaTeX has `\index` only as dummy without action. `\makeindex` redefines `\index` to write an entry into the `.idx` file.

Correction:

```
\makeindex % redefines \index
\LetLtxMacro\oldindex\index
```